# How do i compare the elements of a loop?

Tags: java

**Here is the code:**

```
public class JavaApplication3 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter number of trains");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    int minmin;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("enter hour of arrival");
        int hour = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter minute of arrival");
        int min = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("how many minutes will it stay in the station?");
        int stay = input.nextInt();
        minmin = min + stay;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to compare the hours of each train. i tried doing it with an array but it gets filled with the same element. What's a better way to do it?

Comment: You will also need an array to store the arrival details of all trains then you can do  your comparisons. Better you make a class `TrainArrivalDetails` having data members train arrival hours, min and stay mins. Then maintain an array of objects of type `TrainArrivalDetails`.

Comment: @Uday But how do i make an array that stores the arrival hours? If i put it inside the  for loop it stores the same hour n times.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another class to store trains

```
class Train {
    int hourOfArrival;
    int minuteOfArrival;
    int stay;

    public Train(int hourOfArrival, int minuteOfArrival, int stay) {
        this.hourOfArrival = hourOfArrival;
        this.minuteOfArrival = minuteOfArrival;
        this.stay = stay;
    }
}
```

And then create an array to store them

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter number of trains");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        int minmin;
        Train[] trains = new Train[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("enter hour of arrival");
            int hour = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter minute of arrival");
            int min = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("how many minutes will it stay in the station?");
            int stay = input.nextInt();
            trains[i] = new Train(hour, min, stay);
            minmin = min + stay; // no idea what this does
        }
    }
}
```

Now the ith entry in array trains is the train you want

Comment: And how will that help me compare their hours with eachother? Basically what i need to do is, check the hour and minute they arrived, then check for how long they will stay ( that's why i decided to add the number of minutes they stay with the min they arrived, so minmin), and determine which train will leave faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Train {
    int hourOfArrival;
    int minuteOfArrival;
    int stay;
    int hourOfDeparture;
    int minuteOfDeparture;
    // int order;

    public Train(int hourOfArrival, int minuteOfArrival, int stay) {
        this.hourOfArrival = hourOfArrival;
        this.minuteOfArrival = minuteOfArrival;
        this.stay = stay;
        this.minuteOfDeparture = (minuteOfArrival + stay) % 60;
        this.hourOfDeparture = hourOfArrival + ((minuteOfArrival + stay) / 60);
    }
}


public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter number of trains");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        Train[] trains = new Train[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("enter hour of arrival");
            int hour = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter minute of arrival");
            int min = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("how many minutes will it stay in the station?");
            int stay = input.nextInt();
            trains[i] = new Train(hour, min, stay);
            // your logic to compare the train departure time
        }
        // your logic to compare the train departure time
    }
}
```

I think the above code will give you sufficient data to compare the departure time of each trains and get the train which will leave platform earlier or may be you can find the order in which they leave the platform.
*I have left the logic for comparing departure times for you. you can try that part.*;)

Comment: I have no idea how to compare them. I tried sorting by Arrays.sort but it doesn't work. I'm just getting started, so i haven't worked with classes before. It took me 1 hour just to get it to print the array... haha, but i finally did it.